# Fixing scope in multiple js nested functions within object

Tags: javascript

```
var game = {

    num: 0,
    playerOne: undefined,
    playerTwo: undefined,

    setPlayerNum: function() {
        swal({ 
                title: "Players",
                text: "Enter Number of Players:",
                type: "input",
                showCancelButton: true,
                closeOnConfirm: false,
                animation: "slide-from-top",
            },
            function (inputValue) {
                //Figure out code to put here
                if (inputValue === "") {
                    swal.showInputError ("Please a Number");
                    return false;
                }
                if (inputValue == 1){
                    swal("Nice!", "You Entered: " + inputValue, "success");
                } else if (inputValue == 2) {
                    swal("Twice as Nice!", "You Entered: " + inputValue, "success");
                }
         });
    }
};
```

I have a bunch of nested functions and my grasp on scope has gotten away from me. How can I make it so that function(inputValue) stores the input from setPlayerNum: function() in playerOne: undefined,? Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return something from your `setPlayerNum` function.